# How to change autocompletes in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I have a form, and I want to create an object or something, I use `document.getElementById('example').value`. Thing is, the first time I type 'value' in a new JS file and then enter my comma or semicolon, 'value' changes to ariaValueMax. I know this is a minor inconvenience at worst, but is there any way I can change this? This happens everytime I make a project with JavaScript.

Also, when I'm in my server.js file, sometimes I forget to create a variable before trying to do something with it in express. So if I type something like this:

```
const express = require('express');
app.listen.....
```

I end up with this:

```
const express = require('express');
const { appendFile } = require('fs');

appendFile.listen......
```

Is there any way I can change this settings as well? (the one where it auto creates the require('fs') line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can only answer your first question: You have to edit `settings.json` to tell Intellisense to not accept autocomplete on your "commit character" (in this instance, the semicolon). So first, you have to edit that file:

- Windows `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`
- MacOS `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`
- Linux `$HOME/.config/Code/User/settings.json`

Then, add the following JSON node:

`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false`

Finally, restart your editor, and it should be good to go. Here is an example of my settings.json file:

```
{
    "go.formatTool": "goimports",
    "editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter": false
}
```